# How do I freeze System Time on Mac

Tags: macos

I'm trying to test if a game relies on the current system time for its RNG, but I haven't found a way to freeze the system time in order to try it out. Is there any way to do this on Mac?

Comment: If you're referring to the wall clock time, I don't know if there's any way to freeze it, but you could set it back to a specified value via Terminal with something like 'sudo date 1215000019'

Comment: I've tried that but I haven't been able to make sure that the time was the exact same when testing the game's RNG.